# .htaccess: clean URL with parameter "images" doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-parameters

I've just started trying to figure out how to make clean URLs with .htaccess but it seems I've run into a wall straight away... I've got the following simple .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

It mostly works as expected: *mysite.com/somepage* goes to *mysite.com/index.asp?id=somepage* etc.

Except when the id is 'images'. When I try  *mysite.com/images* it displays: *mysite.com/images/?id=images* (though the page still loads fine)

By the way *mysite.com/images/* (with a slash) works ok. I've been searching for a solution for the last few days and that's the best I could get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `images` is a directory Apache's `mod_dir` module adds a trailing slash after your rewrite rules. You can turn this feature off and add a trailing slash yourself:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on

# add a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```